# facebook graph api picture - get full url with .jpg

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to access my user image from FB with graph api by accessing the user `id` like so: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/<USER_ID>/picture`
However for my code to work, i need the real path to the image like 
`http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/******_**************_********_q.jpg`
[FBs doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/) shows that by adding `?callback=foo` i can get an output, but in practice it doesnt seem to work.
any suggestions for getting the full path to my image with that `.jpg` extension from `graph api` or with the `user id`, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback is for javascript requests,

For php,try appending a `redirect=false` in url.

Do a curl request to,

https://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?redirect=false

If you want to use callback in js,

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?callback=?',function (resp) {
    $('body').html(resp.data.url);
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/4Vh9b/)

[Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

Comment: thank you,  do you know how to parse this? it doesnt look like `json`

Comment: `redirect=false` returns a valid json. Just `json_decode()` the curl response.

Comment: Please remember the future api calls for picture will always return json data instead of forwarding to the original image. See February 6, 2013 breaking changes in https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Answer (score 1):

**USE FOLLOWING  YOU NEVER GET WRONG RESULT **

```
$URL='FB GRAPH API URL';
$headers = get_headers($URL, 1); // make link request and wait for redirection
    if(isset($headers['Location'])) {
      $URL = $headers['Location']; // this gets the new url
    }
    $url_arr = explode ('/',$URL);
    $ct = count($url_arr);
    $name = $url_arr[$ct-1];
    $name_div = explode('.', $name);
    $ct_dot = count($name_div);
    $img_type = $name_div[$ct_dot -1];
    $pos = strrpos($img_type, "&");//many time you got in url
    if($pos)
    {
        $pieces = explode("&", $img_type);
        $img_type = $pieces[0];

    }

    $imagename = imgnameyouwant'.'.$img_type;
    $content = file_get_contents($URL);
    file_put_contents("fbscrapedimages/$imagename", $content);
```